# How to divide a list by a variable haskell

Tags: list, haskell, division

Doing a small project but after hours of work i still cant work out how to divide every element in a list by a variable

```
diver xs = map divhs j
       where divhs = div hs
                hs = tupleTest1 xs
                 j = jot xs
```

wont work and neither does

```
 map (/ j) hs
```

anyone help at all would be most welcome

yours truly
haskell scrub

Comment: what is `jot` ?

Comment: Please provide complete example + error messages

Comment: map (`div` 2) [1,2,3,4,5,6] evaluates as [0,1,1,2,2,3], but from your code it looks like you're trying to do something more complicated...

Comment: this is the latest function in a series of functions defining themselves one after another, jot xs is taking the length of the last of a list of lists intended to represent a graph

Comment: from hundreds of error messages im guessing that the problem lies in the type but I simply am not familiar enough with haskell types to understand

Comment: Well, `map (/ j) hs` most certainly does work, provided `j` is a dividable number and `hs` a list of such numbers. Apparently the problem lies elsewhere and e.g. `hs` is _not_ a list of numbers. Always give your functions type signatures, so you'll see mistakes right where they are, not somewhere completely different. (Also, always use type signatures because they make it much easier to understand what your code is supposed to be doing.)

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to your problem, but note that the code as given doesn't even parse. You can't indent Haskell code like this; all the bindings in a `where` block must start at the same indentation. (You can add space before the `=` if you want those to line up, though I daresay this is more often than not a rather bad idea.)

Comment: I have all my code lined up correctly in my actual terminal I was just a bit sloppy transferring it as I surf the net and code on two different computers, largely due to the limited capacities of both individually

Comment: Then please use SSH, or FTP, or heck, Email or whatever to move code between the two computers. How are we supposed to analyse the problem if you post code that has completely new issues, and probably does _not_ include the real problem?

Comment: fair point my apologies

Answer (score 1):

```
 where divhs = div hs
          hs = tupleTest1 xs
           j = jot xs
```

This is not a correct indentation. The first nonspace character of each line (after `where`) is what matters. Since each line starts as more indented than the previous, the whole `where` block is parsed as if it were on a single line.

```
   where divhs = div hs hs = tupleTest1 xs j = jot xs
```

Hence, errors arise, especially since `hs` and `j` are being parsed as additional arguments, and there are too many `=` signs on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion with `map` should work.
See below my example in ghci:

```
Prelude> let mylist = 1:2:3:4:5:[]
Prelude> mylist
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> let diver xs d = map (/ d) xs
Prelude> diver mylist 2
[0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5]
Prelude>
```

or with your short version

```
Prelude> map (/ 2) mylist
[0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5]
```

---

Based on your comments and your error message

```
 couldn't match expected type '[[int]]' with actual type int - * In the second argument of map' , namely j' - In the expression: map divhs j
```

the problem is that the input variable `j` is not an int as you're expecting, but instead a list of lists of int.
The problem thus probably lies in your function `jot` because you set `j` with `where j = jot xs`.

---

You say that `jot` returns you a number. I would recommend

- trying whether `diver` works if you manually input arguments
- making sure `jot` does not actually return something like `[[1337]]`. If it actually returns a list of lists, like the error message suggests, yet you think it is only one number, then it might be the case that it is just a single int wrapped into a list of lists.

If the second bullet point is the case, you could unpack it as a quick fix (but it would be preferable to fix your code of `jot`) :

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let myunpack (x:xs) = unpackagain x
Prelude|                        where
Prelude|                          unpackagain (y:ys) = y
Prelude| :}
Prelude> myunpack [[123]]
123
```

Comment: absolutely positive

Comment: it cant produce anything other than a list of numbers no matter what the input is

Comment: I just did it again and my error message is                                                                    -                                                                                                                                   -      * couldn't match expected type '[[int]]' with actual type `int`                                   -      * In the second argument of `map' , namely `j'                                                       -        In the expression: map divhs j                                                                   -        In an equation for `diver` :

Comment: @BenjBarrett then your input variable `j` is apparently not an integer, but instead it is a list of lists of int

Comment: diver xs                                                                                                                         -   = map div hs j                                                                                                         -   where                                                                                                                     -           hs = tupleTest1 xs                                                                                          -           j = jot xs

Comment: its meant to be a list of numbers formed of the lengths of lists in a list

Comment: any advice on how to fix the type?

Comment: @BenjBarrett I cannot really read that badly formatted comment. You might want to include your error message in your question, as well as any further details that need nice formatting. Basically what it means when `j` has the wrong type is that your `j = jot xs` is not returning what you think it would. The mistake is probably within your function `jot` or further back

Comment: as soon as i remove any attempt at this function everything is working perfectly :[

Comment: and jot and tupleTest1 are both returning a number and list of numbers respectively